# How can I create floating objects in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, special-effects

I want to create a floating object (or objects) when time freezes.

Zach king created a video that throws popcorn in the air, then when the time freezes, the camera moves around.

Search : 'Zachking Popcorn' then see the floating popcorns for more info that what I exactly saying

How can I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is accomplished during shooting and is not an editorial effect. An set of DSLRs (digital still cameras) arranged in an arc are triggered to all take a shot at the same instant. The individual frames are strung into a sequence and treated as a motion clip. There are lots of examples of this on the web.

You can do similar things using CGI, but it's not a simple task and it isn't cheap.

Edit:

You asked for a tutorial but I don't know of any, so...

[Here's a demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OruWu1hZe9M)

[Here's a cheaper alternative](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5w7y8-V7i8)

Comment: Thank you for your good answer can you give a tutorial link ...